# Trouble using Bootstrap for Django 3

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Bootstrap and thought [this library](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) looked pretty neat. However, when I try to use one of the template tags, there is no styling, just a plain ol' HTML-form. Stuff I have already done:

- Added `'bootstrap3',` to my `settings.py`
- Loaded the library in the top of my template

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{% block title %}
    Edit {{ thing.name }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit "{{ thing.name }}"</h1>
    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {% bootstrap_form form %}
       {% buttons %}
       <button type="submit">{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}Submit</button>
    </form>
       {% endbuttons %}

{% endblock content %}
```

And just for the record - `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'collection',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'registration',

]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Nothing happens" - you get no form at all? You get a form, but it's not styled? You get no HTML at all? You get an error message?

Comment: @JoshKelley edited my question

Answer (score 3):

If things are mostly working, but the styling is missing, it's likely because you're not pulling in the Bootstrap CSS. The django-bootstrap3's README omits this, but its [quickstart example template](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#example-template) has the necessary details.

```
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{# Display a form #}
<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post" class="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
    </button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

(For a real site, of course, you'll probably want to add `{% bootstrap_css %}` and `{% bootstrap_javascript %}` to your base template.)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my own problem. @JoshKelly's answer was part of the solution. I just loaded the CSS and Javascript inside of my `{% block %}` of content. Like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load bootstrap3 %}


{% block title %}
    Edit {{ thing.name }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
    <h1>Edit "{{ thing.name }}"</h1>
    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {% bootstrap_form form %}
       {% buttons %}
       <button type="submit">{% bootstrap_icon "star" %}Submit</button>
    </form>
       {% endbuttons %}

{% endblock content %}
```

As Josh mentioned, this does not look pretty, so I'll make sure to add this to my base.html.